# how to update a table with a join or left join condition in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have tables

```
Table A
 a_id
 b_id
 a_field_1
 a_field_2
 a_field_3

Table B
 b_id
 b_field_1
 b_field_2
 b_field_3
```

if I want to update `a_field_1` only if `b_field_1` mets certain condition ? how to do that ? i tried this but it doesn't work

```
UPDATE A SET A.a_field_1 = 1 , A.a_field_2 = 2
WHERE B.b_field_1 = 1 AND A.b_id = B.b_id;
```

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to make it work? Maybe it is easier to debug this when you share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

According to [Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-update.html) you can use like below:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = [ ROW ] ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
        } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

Sample Query:

```sql
UPDATE A
SET a_field_1 = 1, a_field_2 = 2
FROM B
WHERE
  B.b_field_1 = 1 
  AND A.b_id = B.b_id;
```